# Byobu prints out non-standard escape sequences at startup

Tags: 22.04, tmux, byobu, windows-11

I’m experiencing an issue with Byobu where non-standard escape sequences are being printed when I start a session. My prompt, which should display as `andy@msi-ge62 ~`, is surrounded by these sequences, appearing like this after launching Byobu:

```
^[[>0;10;1candy@msi-ge62 ~ 0;10;1c
```

It was working fine prior to today. I'm not sure what happened.

I am using Windows 11 command prompt as the terminal emulator. It doesn't seem to happen in some other terminal emulators, PUTTY for example. I have been using Windows command prompt because it's the only terminal in which all of the function keys work properly for me in Byobu.

I'm using:

- Byobu version 5.133
- tmux 3.2a
- Ubuntu Server 22.04.
- Client is Windows 11 22H2 (Build 22621.1702)

I can't replicate this issue on other Linux hosts with Byobu using the same Windows terminal emulator.

Here's what I've tried so far to resolve the issue:

- Checked the TERM environment variable outside of Byobu. It's set to  xterm-256color.
- Reset Byobu's configuration by renaming the ~/.byobu directory. This didn't change the behavior.
- Used a clean .bashrc.
- My shell's PS1 configuration seems to be normal.
- Uninstalled and purged tmux and Byobu then reinstalled them both fresh.

I'm unsure of how to proceed with troubleshooting this issue. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Something sets an invalid or too low escape timeout for your tmux (which is Byobu's underhood), so `tmux set-option -sg escape-time 1` may help.

Comment: You might want to change this to 1000 as it's set in milliseconds. For reference, the default value is 500